# MS Word Automation - find the page number where a table is located

Tags: c#, ms-word, automation, office-interop

I have a Word document that contains 10 tables. When I read values in these tables, I want to give a warning to operator to check table 4 on page 5.
I can get the table number, but is there a way to indicate on what page that table is? A fragment of my code is below:

```
int nTable = 0;
int nPage = 0;
foreach (Word.Table tb in doc.Tables)
{
  nTable++;
  nPage = PageNumberForTable(nTable); // I need a function like this
  numRows = tb.Rows.Count;
  numColumns = tb.Columns.Count;

  for (int row = 1; row <= numRows; row++) 
  {
    for(int col = 1; col <= numColumns; col++) 
    {
        var cell = tb.Cell(row, col); 
        cellValue = CleanRASpace(cell.Range.Text); 
        if(cellValue == 2) 
        {
           MessageBox.Show("Check table " + nTable + " on page " + nPage);
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the page number the table is on with:

```
table.Range.Information[Word.WdInformation.wdActiveEndAdjustedPageNumber];
```

When you say you need a function like:

```
nPage = PageNumberForTable(nTable);
```

Seems odd… I would think you would possibly need two methods, one to get a table from a name (Title) another to get all the tables on a given page. To get the tables on a given page I used a list to hold them as it is possible there is more than one table on that page. In the word document I set the table `Titles` to table1, table2, table3… etc… Also if a table splits pages it will return the page the table ends on. Hope this helps.

```
private static int GetTablePageNumberFromTitle(string inTitle, Word.Document doc) {
  foreach (Word.Table tb in doc.Tables) {
    if (tb.Title == inTitle) {
      return tb.Range.Information[Word.WdInformation.wdActiveEndAdjustedPageNumber]; 
    }
  }
  return -1;
}

private static List<Word.Table> GetTablesOnPage(int targetPage, Word.Document doc) {
  List<Word.Table> tablesOnPage = new List<Word.Table>();
  int curPage = -1;
  foreach (Word.Table tb in doc.Tables) {
    curPage = tb.Range.Information[Word.WdInformation.wdActiveEndAdjustedPageNumber];
    if (curPage == targetPage) {
      tablesOnPage.Add(tb);
    }
  }
  return tablesOnPage;
}
```

Some tests

```
  Console.WriteLine("--------------");
  Console.WriteLine("Get page table named 'table3' is on...");
  int pageNum = GetTablePageNumberFromTitle("table3", doc);
  Console.WriteLine("'table3 is on page: " + pageNum);
  Console.WriteLine("--------------");
  Console.WriteLine("Get page table named 'table2' is on... It starts on page 2 and ends on page 3");
  pageNum = GetTablePageNumberFromTitle("table2", doc);
  Console.WriteLine("'table2 is on page: " + pageNum);
  Console.WriteLine("--------------");
  Console.WriteLine("Get tables on page 4");
  List<Word.Table> allTables = GetTablesOnPage(4, doc);
  foreach (Word.Table tb in allTables) {
    Console.WriteLine(tb.Title + " is on page " + 4);
  }
  Console.WriteLine("--------------");
  Console.WriteLine("Get tables on page 5");
  allTables = GetTablesOnPage(5, doc);
  foreach (Word.Table tb in allTables) {
    Console.WriteLine(tb.Title + " is on page " + 5);
  }
```

Comment: John, thank you very much. The code you provided works fine. I don't need to create a function (I was trying to explain it as clearly as possible, but I caused more confusion :) ).